# Easiest way to match transaction totals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal

I am trying to add paypal to my site. I am using their REST API and what I am trying to do is let the user determine the amount they are going to deposit. I can get the total in the creation of the payment, but I am not sure how to pass that to the execution part without a complicated object array system. Any ideas?

Here is an example of how I create the order and execute an order:

```js
router.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.amount_to_deposit)
    var create_payment_json = {
      "intent": "sale",
      "payer": {
          "payment_method": "paypal"
      },
      "redirect_urls": {
          "return_url": `${domain}success`,
          "cancel_url": `${domain}cancel`
      },
      "transactions": [{
          "custom": req.user.steamid,
          "item_list": {
              "items": [{
                  "name": "Deposit",
                  "sku": "001",
                  "price": "25",
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "quantity": 1
              }]
          },
          "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "25"
          },
          "description": `Deposit UserID:${req.user.steamid}`
      }]
  };
  
  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
          if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
            res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
          }
        }
    }
  });
  
  });

  router.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
    const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;
    console.log(req.query)
    const execute_payment_json = {
      "payer_id": payerId,
      "transactions": [{
          "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "25"
          }
      }]
    };
  
    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error.response);
          throw error;
      } else {
          if (payment.transactions[0].custom) {
            console.log(payment.transactions[0].custom)
          }
          res.send('Success');
      }
  });
  });
```

I can get the amount the user wants to pay using body params, but how do I get that to the success route and therefore the execute payment json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the old v1 payments REST API?

The current API is v2/checkout/orders, [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/).  Capturing an order (roughly equivalent to the v1 payments execution) does not require passing an amount.

There is also a node.js SDK for if you find it easier than managing the JSON requests yourself, but either way works as well.

---

It also looks like you're redirecting to the approval_url , which is quite an inferior checkout experience these days. Instead of redirecting, have a PayPal button call your 2 routes (one for create order and one for capture order) using this front end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Don't use any redirects. At all.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, sorry I didn't reply earlier but I've been speed running the docs, my eyes are burning. Anyhow, from what I can understand, the difference is that now you can do the order creating on the front end, send the orderID to the backend, and the backend captures it and all the details. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't create the order on the front end. The front end createOrder function will send a request to your server, which creates the order via API

Comment: Oh I see, so in the front end on create order it should make a fetch request to the backend for the order information that the backend will create. Once the response is received and the user approves the order another fetch request is sent to capture the order in the backend. Do I understand that correctly? Also, I am sorry if I come off as a noob, I'm just entirely self taught so I find it hard to understand the docs sometimes and come here for help.